# El Drawer navigation no actualiza el componente como lo hace Stack navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Cuando trabajo con Stack navigation los componentes se "refrescan" hace la acción useEffect correctamente, en el caso de cuando utilizo Drawer navigation actualiza una única vez, salgo de una screen y entro a otra y regreso a la primera y no se ejecuta el useEffect nuevamente, cosa que si lo hace perfectamente el Stack navigation. ¿Alguien me podría orientar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré solución a mi problema. Cuando se trabaja con Drawer Navigation se debe utilizar useFocusEffect, en vez de useEffect. En la documentación se especifica más al respecto https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen